# Merging Svn Changes After Migrating To Bzr And To Git

Tags: svn, git

I've a centralized repo which began in Svn, was migrated to Bzr, was migrated again to Git. Now there are some residual Svn bits in my Git clone, yet I'm having trouble merging Svn changes from the original Svn repo into a Git clone of the central (migrated) Git repo.

```
git svn log
Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout...
Data from a previous version of git-svn exists, but
    .git/svn
    (required for this version (1.7.x.y) of git-svn) does not exist.
Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
fatal: bad default revision 'refs/remotes/git-svn'
```

After trying to initialize:

```
git svn init [url] --ignore-paths="^(branches|tags)"
git svn fetch --all
git svn log
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history
```

Svn2git doesn't seem appropriate since it makes a whole new local repo.

I recall successfully doing this in the past but can't repeat the results.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After fetching, I always do a

```
git checkout -b svn git-svn
```

to have a git-local `svn` branch that is linked with the remote `git-svn` branch.

Then, it's no problem to access the information of SVN from Git.